# Writability mapping of @OneToMany @MapKeyColumn relationship assumed to be on @Id field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have a game entity, that references two scores via `Map` + `@MapKeyColumn`, where one entity is for the home team and one for the away team:

[image]

I decided to use a `Boolean` column `is_home` for this matter. I mapped the `@MapKeyColumn` relationship **without** `insertable = false, updatable = false`, making that annotation writable regarding the `is_home` column.

Since there may be only one writable field/annotation per column, I had to add `insertable = false, updatable = false` to the `@Id` mapping on the `Score` entity, field `home`, see below.

Game:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Games")
public class Game implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "scheduled_tipoff")
    private LocalDateTime scheduledTipoff;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "is_home")                    <- writable
    private Map<Boolean, Score> scores;

    ...
}
```

Score:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Scores")
@IdClass(ScoreId.class)
public class Score implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "is_home", insertable = false, updatable = false)          <- not writable
    private Boolean home;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "final_score")
    private Integer finalScore;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
    private Game game;

    ...
}
```

ScoreId:

```
public class ScoreId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer game;

    private Boolean home;

    ...
}
```

This results in an exception using EclipseLink:

Exception

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Scores.is_home].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.bbstats.entity.Score --> [DatabaseTable(Scores)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getOrCreateTransactionScopedEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:101)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.Repository.findByNamedQuery(Repository.java:173)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:467)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:453)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findByNamedQuery(BaseEntityService.java:429)
    at net.bbstats.framework.service.BaseEntityService.findAllWithFetchGraph(BaseEntityService.java:385)
    ... 194 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Scores.is_home].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.bbstats.entity.Score --> [DatabaseTable(Scores)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.cannotDeployWithoutPredeploy(EntityManagerSetupException.java:193)
    ... 208 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [Scores.is_home].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.bbstats.entity.Score --> [DatabaseTable(Scores)])
```

**QUESTION**

I understand that JPA implementations might assume every `@Id` field to automatically be writable, but I wonder: does the JPA specify this anywhere?

I currently don't see why this writability assumption is being made.

If it's not specified, is this a bug then?

Comment: You can never change an ID value in an entity, so it is pretty much implied that updatable=false, it is just that eclipseLink tied insertable to updatable in their mappings to match the preexisting read-only concept it had for JPA. JPA requires that if an entity is to ever be inserted, it has an ID value it has control over within the entity - in this case, you are attempting to have the ID be set by some other, external mapping (the game.scores relationship) which doesn't fit what it means to be an entity. This makes it more an embedded object.

Comment: Would you mind posting this as an answer please? It‘s very likely not getting any better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never change an ID value in an entity, so it is pretty much implied that updatable=false; doing so is creating a new identity and needs to be treated as an entirely different entity.

The error message is a hold over from pre-JPA. EclipseLink tied insertable to updatable in their mappings to match the preexisting read-only concept it already had. EclipseLink (and the definition of an entity within JPA) requires that if an entity is to ever be inserted, it has an ID value it has control over within the entity - in this case, you are attempting to have the ID be set by some other, external mapping (the 'game.scores' relationship) which doesn't fit what it means to be an entity. This makes it more an embedded object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able successfully persist a `Game` entity with several Scores, after adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to your `@OneToMany` mapping:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "game", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // added cascading
@MapKeyColumn(name = "is_home")
private Map<Boolean, Score> scores;
```

Example:

```java
Game game = new Game();
game.setId(4);
// ...
      
Score score1 = new Score();
score1.setGame(game);
score1.setHome(true);
score1.setFinalScore(25);
      
Score score2 = new Score();
score2.setGame(game);
score2.setHome(false);
score2.setFinalScore(26);
      
game.getScores().put(score1.getHome(), score1);
game.getScores().put(score2.getHome(), score2);
      
entityManager.persist(game);
```

the following sql was generated:

```
23:27:50,396 DEBUG SQL:127 - 
/* insert com.my.entities.Game */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.TST_GAMES (gm_id) values (?)
23:27:50,408 DEBUG SQL:127 - 
/* insert com.my.entities.Score */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.TST_SCORES (final_score, is_home, game_id) 
values (?, ?, ?)

23:27:50,415 DEBUG SQL:127 - 
/* insert com.my.entities.Score */
insert into TEST_SCHEMA.TST_SCORES (final_score, is_home, game_id) 
values (?, ?, ?)

23:27:50,440 DEBUG SQL:127 - 
update TEST_SCHEMA.TST_SCORES  
set sc_is_home=? 
where sc_is_home=? and sc_game_id=?

23:27:50,443 DEBUG SQL:127 - 
update TEST_SCHEMA.TST_SCORES  
set sc_is_home=? 
where sc_is_home=? and sc_game_id=?
```

It was tested with Hibernate 5.4.10.Final. (without adding above mentioned cascading hibernate generates exception as well)

Comment: I know I can map it alternatively like this, thanks. But it's not what I was asking. The question was, whether the assumption by any JPA provider to expect the `@Id` field to be writable ist wrong or not. This would apply to the `MapKey` annotation as well BTW.

Comment: You did not provide exact scenario that lead to the mentioned in your question exception. Please check my updated answer. Do you use the same approach for `Game` saving? If so, adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` may help.

Comment: The exception happens on WildFly 20 when deploying/starting the app. So no reading and no storing involved. The exception is EclipseLink-only. I just added the hibernate tag to attract more attention.